# Should I use Excel for managing classes and attributes?

Tags: python, csv, class, instance, nested-lists

I have a class with 10 attributes, which I plan to use to create about 100 instances.
If I want to adjust staring values of the attributes, it seems like a good idea to read them from the table.
I tried 'in-code solutions', for example nested lists, but I always end up with messy code.
Is it a good idea to use CSV instead? Or are there better ways of solving such management problem?

Comment: If you just want to store a value and access it, a `json` or `csv` would be more than enough, a spreadsheet is overkill and inefficient at the same time.   
If the data is not huge, can be stored in memory, and is not required to be stored in a file, your in-code solutions would be better.  
Could you provide a bit more info? Maybe we can make your solution a little less messy.

Comment: CSV's are a great way to solve this problem. Any type of file, either JSON, XML, CSV could do the trick. Which is best? Depends on the scope of the project. Is this a personal project or for work? If it's personal, I would keep it simple and use a CSV.